# Add new checkout step to force user registration

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, checkout

I want to add a new checkout step, and It checks whether the user is logged in or not. If yes, the user can skip this step and go to next step (shipment step), if not, the user needs to register in this step.

I am very new in Magento so I need your help on how to do it.
I have read this

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

but I don't know how to collect the input field and create a customer. I want this happen only when the place order is clicked and the order can link to this newly created customer.

Could anyone help me on this!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this qualifies as an answer but you can do what you are trying to do fairly easily in magento admin panel.
Go in `Store->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Allow Guest Checkout` and set it to no after unchecking the checkbox that disables it.